# Can't figure out a simple mathematical equation

Tags: javascript, math

What I would like to do is replace the two if statements with a single mathematical formula. I can't for the life of me figure out how, as mathematics was never my strong point. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>

var x, y, z;
x = 200;
y = 100;
i = 0;

 while(z != y) {

    i++;

    if (x < y) z = x + i;
    if (x > y) z = x - i;

    document.write(z + "<br>");

}


</script>
```

Edit: the real code looks like this. It's not too pretty, was hoping I could shrink it down to two lines.

```
if (prevposX < newposX) posX = prevposX + animStep_;
if (prevposX > newposX) posX = prevposX - animStep_;
if (prevposY < newposY) posY = prevposY + animStep_;
if (prevposY > newposY) posY = prevposY - animStep_;
```

Edit:

It has been a while, but I believe the Modulus (%) operator would have helped me. I've now moved on to a library to do graphics for me so I didn't need it in the end.

Comment: What should happen if `x == y`?

Comment: If `x===y`, then _while_ loop is never terminates.

Comment: To me it seems like the loop in all might be superfluous and could be replaced by a simple mathematical function. If you can explain why you are doing these calculations at ll, preferably with an example, maybe we can help find a neater solution?

Comment: The code is posted is a simplified version of the code I am using to animate the movement of a checker piece on a checkers game I am coding. I have to smoothly transition the movement of the piece from one square to another, inside a game loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

```
z = x + ((x<y) ? i : -i)
```

This assumes that when `x >= y` then you want to `-i`. If you want to stick exactly to your original you need a second ternary operator, which gets a bit messy:

```
z = x + ((x<y) ? i : ((x>y) ? -i : 0))
```

Frankly, it might be clearer to just keep it on 2 lines with 2 if statements like you already have.

Comment: Ok I will do as you have said and leave the code, but it looks like this (see edit)